# Sorting strings on a circle

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

I have a list of strings like "AAAA","BAAA", "BBAA", "BBBA", "BBBAA" etc. (In reality they are longer, more complicated strings) I would like to sort them on a circle. All strings on a circle are a fixed edit distance, by substitution or insertion (say L) from some reference string (not in the list), but the distance to one another can be up to 2L.

I want to organize the strings on this circle such that the sequences are -roughly- sorted by their distance to each other. Meaning closer points (in radians) on the circle, have smaller edit distance with high probability. What is the best approach to do this? (Perfect sort cannot be possible for arbitrary input). I'm thinking insertion sort may be the best approach.

Note: This is not about translating to radial coordinates, my question is about the order of points. The last point on the circle would be neighboring the first point, so a simple distance sort using some point on the circle as a reference is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Please note: "distance from each other" only has meaning if the order is not changed, but you'll be changing the order by sorting, so you'll lose the meaning of distance.

Comment: I have radial distance and edit-distance. I would like to minimize the discrepancy between radial distance and edit-distance. I agree that this is not a proper sort.

Comment: Does your minimization consider *all* combinations of "distance from each other", or only adjacent strings?

Comment: Does your "edit distance" metric have any desirable mathematical properties that would help reduce the search space?

Comment: Have you yet worked at all with a classic regression algorithm, or a genetic algorithm perhaps?  What do you have in mind for an error metric (i.e. how bad is the solution compared to the ideal)?

Comment: Looks like a traveling salesman problem with some ad-hoc weight function. It seems that your metric satisfies triangle inequality, and there are good heuristic TSP solvers for such metrics.